# Cloud Foundry Deployment in Travis

Tags: ibm-cloud, travis-ci, cloud-foundry, pipeline, devops

I know I can do this: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/cloudfoundry

Now in .travis.yml, it will have

```
deploy:
    edge: true
    provider: cloudfoundry
    username: hulk_hogan@example.com
    password: supersecretpassword
    api: https://api.run.pivotal.io
    organization: myawesomeorganization
    space: staging
```

Altough password can be encrypted by running

```
travis encrypt --add deploy.password
```

I don't want to put username and password(even it's encrypted) in yml file, is there  another way for Travis to deploy apps to Cloud Foundry (or IBM Bluemix)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of passing credentials with Cloud Foundry. Putting them in your .yml file is just one option.

1. You can set them manually with the command **cf set-env**, as explained here: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#view-env
2. If you are afraid of the CLI, Bluemix also allows you to create user-defined environment variable with its GUI : https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/simple-data-pipe/wiki/Create-a-user-defined-environment-variable-in-Bluemix#use-the-bluemix-user-interface

> I don't want to put username and password(even it's encrypted) in yml file

FYI, the .yml file does not leave your computer/CI server and is just read once by Cloud Foundry.